# Как использовать логическую конструкицю handlebars в .net?

Tags: c#, .net, handlebars

Интересует как сделать логическую конструкцию правильно:

1. Нужно отобразить в шаблоне в зависимости от типа Arrival или Departure
2. К примеру, если TerminalNumber будет равен null. Как не показывать текст 'and TerminalNumber {{TerminalNumber}}'

{{Или Arrival или Departure}} AirportCode **{{AirportCode}}** and TerminalNumber **{{TerminalNumber}}** was not found in our system of Flight {{FlightNumber}}

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: А зачем вообще шаблонизатор в C#, если есть интерполяция строк?

Comment: Это для отправки email. Я прокидываю данные в html. А сейчас сижу, и не могу понять как при условии что если TerminalNumber = null, не выводить текст: "and TerminalNumber". Возможно, я не правильно понял. Есть другой способ?

Comment: А я не понял, как это вообще у вас работает. Код вы не показали несмотря на комментарии выше.

Answer (score 1):

используйте IF ELSE в вашем шаблоне:

```
{{#ifCond arg1 condition arg2}}
       True clause {{variable}}
{{else}}
       False clause {{variable}}
{{/ifCond}}
```

вот тут полное решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47134327